# Javascript class events set for an instance fire for all previous instances

Tags: javascript, class, events, dom-events

I have a class which creates `mousedown` listeners for each LI. However, a click to the LI of the first instance results in events firing for every LI instance which was created after it. If you create a 3rd instance, the click on the 1st instance will result in all 3 firing and a click on the 2nd results in the 2nd and 3rd firing, etc.

To duplicate, run the jsfiddle and click on the two links (one after the other) which will create two UL elements each containing an LI element. `Alerts()` are set up to show each event firing. If you continue to click on the links, you will see how the events continue to stack.

I'm new to creating classes in javascript, so I've obviously missed something, but can't see why the events for the multiple instances are not separate. In case you're wondering, I've created my class the way I did to allow for static variables and methods. I am not using jQuery.

I've posted [a jsfiddle of the below code](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/n9zoLcos/10/)

**UPDATE**
Fixed errors due to paring complicated code down for SO. I've updated to reflect multiple LI elements being created in each UL (the number is dynamic and db driven) and the ID's being unique.

```
<div id="outer">
    <a href="#" onclick="edit('g123')">Click here first id=g123</a>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onclick="edit('g234')">Click here second id=g234</a>
</div>    
    
<script>

listbox = (function (id) {
        var currentul = "";
        var counter = 0;
    
        function listbox(id) {
            this.id = id;
        };
    
        // show or hide once all the properties are set
        listbox.prototype.go = function () {
            this.initlistbox();
            this.addlisteners();
        }
    
        // create the elements for drag and drop between two list boxes
        listbox.prototype.initlistbox = function () {
            var _this = this;
            var divlist = document.createElement('div');
            divlist.style.minHeight = '100px';
            divlist.style.width = '300px'
            divlist.style.outline = '1px solid blue'
    
            // the UL
            var ul = document.createElement('ul');
            ul.setAttribute('id', 'ulchosen-' + this.id);
    
            // track which UL is active for keystrokes
            ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
                currentul = this.id;
            }, false);
    
            // add the ul to the div
            divlist.appendChild(ul);
    
            divouter = document.getElementById("outer");
            // add the div to the body
            divouter.appendChild(divlist);
    
            // The LI
            // create LI elements
            for (i=0; i < 4; i++){
                var li = document.createElement('li');
                counter++;
                li.setAttribute('id', 'lb-li-chosen-' + counter);
                li.innerHTML = "Hello " + counter + " " + this.id;
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }    
        };
    
        listbox.prototype.addlisteners = function () {
            var _this = this;
    
            var lis = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='lb-li-']");
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
                this.setlilisteners(lis[i]);
            }
        };
    
        listbox.prototype.setlilisteners = function (el) {
            var _this = this;
    
            // click is for non drag, non shift / ctrl
            el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                alert("A: " + _this.id);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }, false);
    
            // mousedown is to select LI elements
            el.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                alert("B: " + _this.id);
                return false;
            }, false);
    
        };
    
        return listbox;
    })();
    
    function edit(id) {
        var a = new listbox(id);
        a.go();
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you use `addEventListener` a new function is stacked for execution. `addEventListener` does not removes the older function. So you have to call it just once per element.

The code below will work.

```
listbox = (function (id) {
    var currentul = "";

    function listbox(id) {
        this.id = id;
    };

    // show or hide once all the properties are set
    listbox.prototype.go = function () {
        this.initlistbox();
    }

    // create the elements for drag and drop between two list boxes
    listbox.prototype.initlistbox = function () {
        var _this = this;
        var divlist = document.createElement('div');
        divlist.style.minHeight = '100px';
        divlist.style.width = '300px'
        divlist.style.outline = '1px solid blue'

        // the UL
        var ul = document.createElement('ul');
        ul.setAttribute('id', 'ulchosen-' + this.id);

        // track which UL is active for keystrokes
        ul.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
            currentul = this.id;
        }, false);

        // add the ul to the div
        divlist.appendChild(ul);

        divouter = document.getElementById("outer");
        // add the div to the body
        divouter.appendChild(divlist);

        // The LI
        // create LI elements
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.setAttribute('id', 'lb-li-chosen-1');
        li.innerHTML = "Hello " + this.id;
        ul.appendChild(li);

        this.setlilisteners(li);

    };

    listbox.prototype.setlilisteners = function (el) {
        var _this = this;

        // click is for non drag, non shift / ctrl
        el.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            alert("A: " + _this.id);
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }, false);

        // mousedown is to select LI elements
        el.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("B: " + _this.id);
            return false;
        }, false);

    };

    return listbox;
})();

function edit(id) {
    var a = new listbox(id);
    a.go();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Unfortunately, multiple LI elements are created for each UL as well and I've update the code and jsfiddle to reflect that. I also accidentally had the id not changing which was a problem with the example (not the bigger code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The logic remains the same. Call `setlilisteners` for each `li` you create.

Comment: I was about to answer that there is no difference between calling setlisteners directly or calling it through addlisteners. When I looked, I saw the bug was in not filtering the call to setlisteners to only include the NEW LI elements which are being created with the new instance. I need the function addlisteners since I have more listeners in place that aren't shown in this code. Thanks for your help. My posted answer shows what the code fix was.

Answer (score 1):

Gustavo's answer helped me locate the bug. I wasn't filtering the LI elements to only include the current UL, so with each additional instance, a listener for ALL the LI elements were being set again. He was trying to tell me this... So here it is:

```
   listbox.prototype.addlisteners = function () {
        var _this = this;

        var lis = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='lb-li-']");
        for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
            // THIS IF STATEMENT WAS MISSING
            if (lis[i].parentNode.id.indexOf("-" + this.id) !== -1){
                this.setlilisteners(lis[i]);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The fiddle is creating multiple LI elements with the same id `lb-li-chosen-1` which is invalid HTML. In some browsers I believe it may result in the query selector returning an array of multiple LI elements with result that each time `.addListeners` is called a new event listener function is added to each LI element defined so far.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the id issue as well as showing that mulitple LI elements are created for each UL as well. The jsfiddle is also updated. My js class is of course much larger and this is trying to make it small enough for SO.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @GustavoAlves and I agree the logic remains the same. `var lis = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='lb-li-']");` still returns an array of every LI element created previously, because the id of all the LI elements created previously starts with "lb-li-"

Comment: Yes that was the problem, but neither of your posts pointed to that line of code nor was as clear as your last comment. But they did help me in finding it myself and that is why I posted the answer I did. Thanks again.